# Unable to open appstore link (PhoneGap)

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova, ios7

Tried both of the following methods so that ppl can click a link in my app and be taken to the app store to review/rate:

```
<a href="itms-apps:://itunes.apple.com/app/id111111111">Rate our App</a>
```

and when this linked is tapped on, nothing happens and i get the following console message:

```
Failed to load webpage with error: The URL can’t be shown
```

Also tried a window.open:

```
$(document).hammer().on('tap', self.frameSelector + ' .rate-us-action', function(){
    window.open('itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id111111111');
});
```

and when tapping attempting this method nothing happens and i get the following console message:

```
 handle url: itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id1111111
```

How do i get my phonegap app to properly open a link to the appstore???

Answer (score 0):

Try this format for <> has to be replaced with the appropriate info:

```
http://itunes.apple.com/app/<APP_NAME>/id<APP_ID>?mt=8
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following link format for Cordova/PhoneGap apps since Cordova 2.2 & iOS 5:

```
itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/appname
```

Simply replace `appname` with your app's name.

```
<a href="itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/appname">Rate our App</a>
```

You can also open the App Store and display a page of apps by your company with the same format:

```
itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/companyname
```

In a link:

```
<a href="itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/companyname">More Apps By Us</a>
```

This works today on iOS 8.1.1 without the Cordova inappbrowser plugin.